# Connection configuration loops - Prosys OPC UA Client

Tags: node.js, opc, node-opcua

I'm using sample codes from documentation and I'm trying to connect to server using Prosys OPC UA Client. I have tried opcua-commander and integration objects opc ua client and it looks like server works just fine.

Here's what is happening:

1. After entering endpointUrl, client adds to url `-- urn:NodeOPCUA-Server-default`.
2. Client asks to specify security settings.
3. Client asks to choose server - only 1 option and it's urn:NodeOPCUA-Server-default.

And it goes back to step 2 and 3 over and over.

If I just minimize prosys client without closing configuration after some time I get this info in terminal:
`Server: closing SESSION  new ProsysOpcUaClient Session15  because of timeout =  300000  has expired without a keep alive
\x1B[46mchannel = \x1B[49m ::ffff:10.10.13.2  port =  51824`

I have tried this project and it works -> [node-opcua-htmlpanel](https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua-htmlpanel). What's missing in sample code then?

After opening debugger I have noticed that each Time I select security settings and hit OK, server_publish_engine reports:

`server_publish_engine:179 Cencelling pending PublishRequest with statusCode BadSecureChannelClosed (0x80860000) length = 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to a specific interoperability issue that was introduced in node-opcua@0.2.2. this will be fixed in next version of node-opcua. The resolution can be tracked here https://github.com/node-opcua/node-opcua/issues/464

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been handled at the [Prosys OPC Forum](https://forum.prosysopc.com/forum/opc-ua-client/connecting-to-node-opc-ua-server/#p3741):

> The error happens because the server sends different
>   EndpointDescriptions in GetEndpointsResponse and
>   CreateSessionResponse.
>
> In GetEndpoints, the returned EndpointDescriptions contain
>   TransportProfileUri=http://opcfoundation.org/UA-Profile/Transport/uatcp-uasc-uabinary.
>   In CreateSessionResponse, the corresponding TransportProfileUri is
>   empty.
>
> In principle, the server application is not working according to
>   specification. The part 4 of the OPC UA specification states that “The
>   Server shall return a set of EndpointDescriptions available for the
>   serverUri specified in the request. … The Client shall verify this
>   list with the list from a DiscoveryEndpoint if it used a
>   DiscoveryEndpoint to fetch the EndpointDescriptions. It is recommended
>   that Servers only include the server.applicationUri, endpointUrl,
>   securityMode, securityPolicyUri, userIdentityTokens,
>   transportProfileUri and securityLevel with all other parameters set to
>   null. Only the recommended parameters shall be verified by the
>   client.”